# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function, following DataTable example

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I'm getting the above mentioned error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var table = $('#mytable1').DataTable();
    $('#mytable1 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        console.log( table.row( this ).data() ); // ERROR
    } );
});
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link href="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="project.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="mytable1" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>US</td><td>NY</td></tr>
            <tr><td>US</td><td>VT</td></tr>
            <tr><td>US</td><td>MA</td></tr>
            <tr><td>US</td><td>ME</td></tr>
            <tr><td>US</td><td>VA</td></tr>
            <tr><td>US</td><td>WV</td></tr>
            <tr><td>CAN</td><td>04</td></tr>
            <tr><td>CAN</td><td>05</td></tr>
            <tr><td>CAN</td><td>06</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="homepage.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried with:

```
jQuery(function($) {}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#myTable').dataTable();`, with a lowercase `d`

Comment: @adeneo, tried that, same result.

Comment: Just place a breakpoint at your click handler and see what's going on, I've recreated your setup (JQ 1.11, DT 1.10) except of Bootstrap and all works fine. Console shows 2 data values of the row you select. Seem's like you have an error in your dependant scripts, make sure all of them are loaded (open developer tools and check the list in Sources tab)

Comment: Removed local references to jQuery and Datatables and replaced with CDN. Must have something wrong with my locally downloaded libs (jquery, datatables, bootstrap).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**fnGetData**](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnGetData) for this :

```
var table = $('#mytable1').DataTable();
$('#mytable1 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log(table.fnGetData(this));
});
```

This outputs the content of the clicked row as an array `[col1, col2]`. Besides that I cannot see any problem with your code.

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/X2Zs9/**